# How can I pass param when I use @selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UIButton, and I want call a method when I click it.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

Meanwhile, I need to pass the tag of UIButton to the click function;

```
- (void) click : (NSInteger) tag{
    NSLog(@"%d tag button clicked",tag);
}
```

But how can I pass the tag param?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selectors are the names of messages. They do not carry data. The solution to your problem is as follows:

```
- (void)click:(id)sender
{
   NSLog("%d tag button clicked", [sender tag])
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't have the references in front of me, but check out the performSelector: set of messages. There is at least one there that takes a parameter.